# Just show class to active tab no class for rest tab

Tags: jquery

In the given example I use ".active" and ".inactive" classes, but i just want to display ".active" class for tab when clicked without the need to apply ".inactive", how can I remove ".inactive" class from code's condition

```
//------ Tabs
                $('#tabs li:first-child a').addClass('active');
        $('#tabs li a:not(:first)').addClass('inactive');
                $('.tab-container').hide();
                $('.tab-container:first').show();

                $('#tabs li a').click(function(){
                    var t = $(this).attr('id');

                    if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){ //this is the start of our condition 

          $('#tabs li a').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');           
                    $(this).removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');

                    $('.tab-container').hide();
                    $('#'+ t + 'C').fadeIn('slow');
                 }
                });
```

**[JSFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/alpeshlahad/dtfbfqbd/7/)**

Comment: Do you need https://jsfiddle.net/v78se1b6/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is!

```
    $('#tabs li:first-child a').addClass('active');
    $('.tab-container').hide();
    $('.tab-container:first').show();
    $('#tabs li a').click(function(){
                   var t = $(this).attr('id');
                 if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){                             
                        $('#tabs li a').removeClass('active');           
                        $(this).addClass('active');

                        $('.tab-container').hide();
                        $('#'+ t + 'C').fadeIn('slow');
                     }
                });
```